# Unique Field - no unique constraint matching given keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables in a postgresql database, namely tec_configurations, tep_cores and tep2tec_bindings. The table tec2tep_bindings references to the primary key fields of the first two tables. The related create statements per table are listed in below sql snippets 2,3 and 4. I get the error indicated in the 1st snippet below. Could you please tell me how I can fix this error? The 'id' field in table TEC_CONFIGURATIONS is already unique since it is a primary key. So, I don't see a reason to get this error message.

**SNIPPET 1 (Error message):**

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
"tec_configurations"
```

**SNIPPET 2 (TABLE tec_configurations):**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEC_CONFIGURATIONS ( 
         ID              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,           
         TEC_ID          INT  NOT NULL,
         HANDLER_MAC     TEXT NOT NULL, 
         PRIMARY_MAC     TEXT, 
         SECONDARY_MAC   TEXT, 
         TERTIARY_MAC    TEXT, 
         EXPECTED_FLOWS  INT DEFAULT 0, 
         VERSION         INT  DEFAULT 0, 
         UUID            TEXT DEFAULT NULL );
```

**SNIPPET 3 (TABLE tep_cores):**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEP_CORES (
         ID     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,                       
         MAC    TEXT,
         UUID   TEXT,
         CORE_NO INT DEFAULT 0);
```

SNIPPET 4 (TABLE tec2tep_bindings)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEC2TEP_BINDINGS (
         ID              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,            
         TEC_ID_FK       INT  NOT NULL REFERENCES TEC_CONFIGURATIONS(ID),
         TEP_CORE_ID_FK  INT  NOT NULL REFERENCES TEP_CORES(ID),
         REPLICA_RANK    INT  DEFAULT 0);
```

Comment: Can't reproduce in PostgreSQL 9.1. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess, since you're issuing `create table if not exists` rather than `create table`: one of the tables exists without the needed unique key (e.g. from lack of a primary key).

(If correct, I'd add this note. Some Postgres core devs were hostile to the idea of adding `if exists` and `if not exists` constructs, objecting thus: "What is supposed to happen when you `create table if not exists`, silently "succeed", and the existing table has a schema different from the one you were hoping for?")

Comment: It was indeed the case that one of the tables were existing from my previous run... I first drop the tables with cascade expression included and then re-created in a clean way. So, it worked... Thanks